# React-native getting a response after making a post request is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express

I am trying to send back a response after making a successful post request in react-native, but the response does not arrive properly.

```
router.route("/addUser").post((req, res) => {
 let name= req.body.name;
  connection.query(
    `INSERT INTO users (id,name) VALUES (NULL,${name})`,

    function (error, results) {
      console.log("REAL RESULTS: " + JSON.stringify(results));
      if (error) throw error;

      res.send("Inserted successfully"); 
    }
  );
});
```

Then, when I try to receive the request and print its content (which is expected to be: **Inserted Successfully**) I get:

{"type":"default","status":200,"ok":true,"headers":{"map":{"x-powered-by":"Express","content-length":"21","connection":"keep-alive","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","etag":"W/"15-fAIFznmhviiIlY1HeyBcwGlWsmo"","date":"Wed, 12 Aug 2020 12:35:59 GMT","cache-control":"public, max-age=0"}},"url":"http://192.168.1.9:3000/database/addUser","bodyUsed":false,"_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":21,"offset":0,"blobId":"aeb788fe-9bab-4641-a0a3-25e5df4c8890","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":21,"offset":0,"blobId":"aeb788fe-9bab-4641-a0a3-25e5df4c8890","__collector":{}}}}

This is my code for making the request:

```
fetch("http://192.168.1.9:3000/database/addUser", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: "Some name",
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: You are logging the entire response object.  Have you tried `console.log(res.text());`?

Comment: It printed this for me:
```function () {
        var rejected = consumed(this);

        if (rejected) {
          return rejected;
        }

        if (this._bodyBlob) {
          return readBlobAsText(this._bodyBlob);
        } else if (this._bodyArrayBuffer) {
          return Promise.resolve(readArrayBufferAsText(this._bodyArrayBuffer));
        } else if (this._bodyFormData) {
          throw new Error('could not read FormData body as text');
        } else {
          return Promise.resolve(this._bodyText);
        }
      }```

Comment: Did you include the extra parentheses? `res.text()`  It is a promise as well, so you might want to chain your promises.  `fetch().then(res => res.text()).then(text => console.log(text));`

Comment: It is still not working

Comment: Are you seeing the same as in the question, or is it different?

Comment: It says it is undefined. I tried using postman, and I got the right result as a response. So, I think the problem is with sending the data back only. So, would this be a problem from express server?

Comment: If postman is returning as expected, then the server is fine and the issue lies within your `fetch` call.

Comment: I tried this but I don't see anything, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fetch("http://192.168.1.9:3000/database/addUser", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "no-cors",
    cache: "no-cache", 
    credentials: "same-origin", 
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: "Some name",
    }),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: It is printing undefined!

Comment: I guess you are passing wrong content-type, in your response you are getting 
"content-type":"text/html"

Comment: I am using the code above and the Content-Type is "application/json"!